# How to define the shapes and orientations of orbitals mathematically in a cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, online-resources, programming, spherical-harmonics

I am not able to match the $d$ and $f$ orbitals in atomic structure worksheet given as homework (see the attached image). I was able to match the $p_{x}$ [image: p_{x}], $p_{y}$ [image: p_{y}], and $p_{z}$ [image: p_{z}]orbitals. But I am facing difficulty with the $d$ and $f$ orbitals. Is it possible to define the shapes and orientations of all the orbitals mathematically in cartesian coordinate system (and graph it on Mathematica, etc.) so that it would be easier for me to understand the structure of orbitals, nodes, shells, etc., for example, the $s$ orbital can be defined as  $(x - x_0 )^2 + (y - y_0 )^2 + ( z - z_0 )^2 = r^2$ which is a sphere[image: s]. I am not sure about other orbitals which are very complicated (I am not introduced to spherical harmonics).

[image: d-orbitals resize]

In the given worksheet I have to match [image: d1], [image: d2], [image: d3], [image: d4], and [image: d5] with $d_{x^2-y^2}$, $d_{zx}$, $d_{3z^2-r^2}$, $d_{yz}$, and $d_{xy}$.

[image: Spherical Harmonics Laplace, Helmholtz, or central force Schrodinger eq. Set  Set  Orthonormal solutions.]

I am having trouble understanding the structure of orbitals, nodes, shells, subshells, etc. Is it possible to define the shapes and orientations of all the orbitals mathematically in cartesian coordinate system (and graph it on Mathematica, etc.). for  example, the s orbital can be defined as a sphere.

Comment: You may be interested in [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)

Comment: Perhaps including axes in the pictures would make it easier.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Jesse, your recent preprints are quite interesting. So far, they've been a great read.

Comment: I'd argue that expressing them in Cartesian coordinates makes it harder, not easier, to understand their structure. Box-like structures profit from being described in Cartesian coordinates. Sphere-like structures profit from being described in spherical coordinates.